# Visual Basic .net iTextSharp create square in pdf

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf

I'm working in Visual Studio 2010 and I have to create PDF file in Visual Basic. I already create PDF using iTextSharp but I have problem because I have no idea how create square like this □ . I need this because my programm should create card with candidates names and squares to mark your choice. Thanks for answer, here is my code:

```
        Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
        Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create))

        pdfDoc.Open()
        pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("□ Exampe Example"))

        pdfDoc.Close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you are using a Unicode-supported font to write this to the pdf. I used "*Arial Unicode MS*" as an example:

```
Private Function GetFont() As Font
    Dim fontLocation As String = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "ARIALUNI.TTF")

    Dim baseFont As BaseFont = baseFont.CreateFont(fontLocation, baseFont.IDENTITY_H, baseFont.NOT_EMBEDDED)

    Return New Font(baseFont, 14, 0)
End Function
```

This will now display correctly in your pdf:

```
    Dim pdfDoc As New Document()
    Dim pdfWrite As PdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, New FileStream("Test.pdf", FileMode.Create))

    pdfDoc.Open()

    Dim f As Font = GetFont()

    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("■ Exampe Example", f))
    pdfDoc.Add(New Paragraph("□ Exampe Example", f))

    pdfDoc.Close()
```